# How to save multiple data with same name attribute in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a form as: 
   **Razor view:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mac, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
            <span class="add-new-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="add_mac"> </span>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mac, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "mac_addr" } })

            @* @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedMac, new SelectList(ViewBag.Macs, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "mac_addr" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedMac, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) *@

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Rendered HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group row new_mac_wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="new_mac_container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-md-2">
        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-1" />
    </div>
</div>
}

<form action="/Users/Register" method="post">
   <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="w3GWVNW8nPHGcTz1kIBbyGu7386qDwfOFNprYBlmF8ve9KzKS47SyVOYFgf_jGFRzOum7oNKUZRKqtIinDP-ed8Lt5kP7kqHFJzrLmgG9P81">    
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" for="Name">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
         <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">
         <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" for="Email">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
         <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="">
         <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" for="Mac">Mac</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3">
         <span class="add-new-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" id="add_mac"> </span>
         <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="mac_addr" name="Mac" type="text" value="">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row new_mac_wrapper">
      <div class="col-md-offset-3">
         <div class="new_mac_container">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3 positioned_relative margin-bottom">
               <input readonly="" name="Mac" type="text" class="form-control" value="12556564">
               <span class="remove_mac remove-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"> </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3 positioned_relative margin-bottom">
               <input readonly="" name="Mac" type="text" class="form-control" value="444444">
               <span class="remove_mac remove-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"> </span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-md-2">
         <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-1">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here I have three input with same name attribute 'Mac'. The additional input(s) having name='Mac' is being generated using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_mac').on('click', function(){
        var mac = $('#mac_addr').val();
        if(!mac){
          alert('Input MAC ADRESS First');
          return;
        }
        var newMAChtml  = '<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-3 positioned_relative margin-bottom">';
            newMAChtml += '<input readonly name="Mac" type="text" class="form-control" value="'+mac+'" >';
            newMAChtml += '<span class="remove_mac remove-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"> </span>';
            newMAChtml += '</div>';
            $('.new_mac_container').append(newMAChtml);
            $('#mac_addr').val('');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.remove_mac', function() {
          $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
});
```

And I want to save these three inputs. I am trying as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(UserViewModel model)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    AccountRegistrationRequestMessage requerstMessage = new AccountRegistrationRequestMessage();
    requerstMessage.FullName = model.Name; 
    requerstMessage.EmailAddress = model.Email; 
    requerstMessage.MacAddresses.Add(model.Mac);

    requerstMessage.RegistrationType = AccountRegistrationEnum.IndividualAccountRegistration;

    Task<AccountRegistrationResponseMessage> response = _interactor.Handle(requerstMessage, cancelToken.Token);

    UserViewModel viewModel = _presenter.Handle(response.Result, model, ModelState);

    if (response.Result.ValidationResult.IsValid)
    {
        //return View("DetailView", viewModel);
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

UserViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Mac { get; set; }
}
```

But Currently only last value of `<input name="Mac" ...` is being saved. I thought of using a for loop and then accessing them via something like `form["Mac"][i]` but obviously that is not going to work.

Am I going about this the right way and if so, does anyone have any suggestions about how this might work?

Comment: Sounds like the presented HTML code is the rendered output from a CSHTML page. Can you provide actual Razor code for it? I suspected you're using `foreach` loop when creating text inputs (most possibly the duplicated `name` attribute come from `@Html.TextBoxFor()` helper).

Comment: Thanks for your time. I just update my question.

Comment: Try replace `public string Mac { get; set; }` with `public List<string> Mac { get; set; }`, since you want to pass more than one textbox with `<input name="Mac" ... />`. Then you can iterate the list to get MAC addresses or simply use `requerstMessage.MacAddresses.AddRange(model.Mac);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple `<input>` elements with same `name="Mac"` attribute (one with `EditorFor` and others are dynamically generated ones), first you should change property type of `Mac`:

```
public string Mac { get; set; }
```

to this one:

```
public List<string> Mac { get; set; }
```

The model binder will treat values in textboxes as string collection and bind them together on POST request. Afterwards, you can retrieve list of MAC addresses using `AddRange`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(UserViewModel model)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    AccountRegistrationRequestMessage requerstMessage = new AccountRegistrationRequestMessage();
    requerstMessage.FullName = model.Name; 
    requerstMessage.EmailAddress = model.Email; 

    // Use ForEach() method to add IEnumerable collection into ICollection
    // requerstMessage.MacAddresses.AddRange(model.Mac); 
    model.Mac.ForEach(x => requerstMessage.MacAddresses.Add(x));

    // other stuff

    UserViewModel viewModel = _presenter.Handle(response.Result, model, ModelState);

    if (response.Result.ValidationResult.IsValid)
    {
        //return View("DetailView", viewModel);
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: getting error: icollection string doesn't contain a definition for addrange for AddRange()

Comment: Is all `Mac` data already passed this time? What is the type of `MacAddresses`? If it's a string, you can't directly use `AddRange` against it. Sorry about that.

Comment: public virtual ICollection<string> MacAddresses { get; set; }. What should I do in that case?

Comment: Try using `requerstMessage.MacAddresses = ((List<string>)requerstMessage.MacAddresses).AddRange(model.Mac)`, `model.Mac.ForEach(x => requerstMessage.MacAddresses.Add(x));` or simply change property type to `List<string>` if you can do that.